# Is there a way to specify that a class does not run any tests in phpunit?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

My question is: is there a way for PHPUnit to ignore certain files during testing?

I looked through the PHPUnit annotations [here](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html) and I was looking for something similar to `doesNotPerformAssertions` but on a class level.

I have a parent class that I want to use to setup my testing environment and for children test classes to extend from it, instead of the TestCase. There are going to be many different TestSuites, each with their own unique setup requirements.

Is it just a matter of removing Test.php from the filename so that PHPUnit doesn't pick it up? Or is there a way to get PHPUnit to ignore my parent test file that will only be responsible for setting up my testing env?

I was also wondering if I am going about this the wrong way and instead I should create a new TestCase. I decided on doing it this way because I could see the setUp and tearDown being the same across a testsuite.

Parent:

```php
namespace Tests\Feature\Sample;

use Tests\TestCase;

class ParentSampleTest extends TestCase
{
    protected function refreshTestDatabase()
    {
        if (! RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated) {
            $this->artisan('db:seed --class=SampleTestSeeder');

            $this->app[Kernel::class]->setArtisan(null);

            RefreshDatabaseState::$migrated = true;
        }

        $this->beginDatabaseTransaction();
    }
}
```

Child:

```php
namespace Tests\Feature\Sample;

use Tests\Feature\Sample\ParentSampleTest;

class ChildSampleCRUDTest extends ParentSampleTest
{
    public function test_it_is_a_test()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you "recreating" what the Laravel `TestCase` does? Never do that, always let the Framework handle itself... If you need to seed for each run, just do [`$this->seed()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#running-seeders) on the `setUp`, so your "parent" class would have it's own `setUp` and in your child you would overwrite it and do `parent::setUp();`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on `phpunit.xml` settings (see `<directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>`), usually, removing `Test` suffix is sufficient. Also, you may declare it as abstract, if it's not intended to be instantiated.